# What size should a custom UITabBarItem image using SVG (as PDF) be in Xcode ios?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have modified the UITabBar in my iOS app to use custom icons. If I make them 45x45 px png then remove the title and change the offset like so:

```
    self.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] init];
    self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"live.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"live.png"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
    UIEdgeInsets insets = { .left = 0, .right = 0, .top = 5, .bottom = -5 };
    self.tabBarItem.imageInsets = insets;
```

Then I get an image that is the correct size (in Portrait only), but pixelated.
So I am now trying to use an SVG image saved as a PDF. I have created a new Xcode image asset, drag and dropped the PDF into it. Selected 'Preserve Vector Data' in the Xcode Interface Builder Attributes Inspector.
But the icon size is now dependant on pixel size. I have tried 20x20px (too small) and 512x512px (too big).

I could carry on trying different sizes until one works. But really need to see some Apple specifications as to how this should work, rather than trying to reverse engineer it. The use of SVGs and PDFs in Xcode is not well documented (AFAICS). The closest it gets is this [Custom Symbol Images](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app?language=objc)  and this [Configuring and Displaying Symbol Images in Your UI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiimage/configuring_and_displaying_symbol_images_in_your_ui?language=objc). Along with [Creating Custom Symbol Images for Your App](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/creating_custom_symbol_images_for_your_app?language=objc). None of which give enough info.

Comment: 45x45px seems to fit correctly btw